# Nonlinear eigenvalue problem $Ax = f(c) x$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a typical eigenvalue problem $Ax=bx$ whose eigenvalues ($b_i$) and corresponding eigenvectors ($v_i$) are known.

We are interested in a new eigenvalue problem of the form $Ax = f(c) x$. In which $f(c)$ is an arbitrary scalar function of the variable $``c"$. Particularly, we are interested in polynomial and rational functions.

The eigenvalues of the new problem can be obtained by solving $f(c_i)=b_i$ (?). The main question is: what can we say about the eigenvectors of the new problem? If $v_i$'s are linearly independent, under what conditions the second problem also has linearly independent eigenvectors?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the set up. If the $v_{i}'s$ are eigenectors with eigenvalues $b_{i}$, are they not precisely the eigenvectors for $f(c_{i})=b_{i}$. Is the base field real or complex? Is $A$ nice in any way? (e.g. diagonalizable, hermetian, unitary, orthogonal, real self-adjoint)

Comment: It's not a new problem, it's the same problem.  Calling the eigenvalue $f(c)$ doesn't change it, or the eigenvector.